# how to access usercontrol value in js/jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, webusercontrol

Suppose i created a user control which contain two textbox, one button

```
 --Start UserControl UserDetails--
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtAddress"></asp:TextBox>
--End UserControl UserDetails-
```

in aspx if i use the same user control,

```
<uc1:UserDetails runat="server" ID="UserDetails1" />
```

1. how do i access the `txtName` using user control id `UserDetails1`?
2. How do i make `$('#UserDetails1').val()` to return value of `txtName`?

Comment: I believe it is `$("#txtName").val()` but the rendered html displayed on the page would reveal the final input ID.

Comment: $("#txtName").val() will work, that I'm well aware of. but with respect to user control id i should be able to access text box value. $('userControl').Val() should return first textbox value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a public property for you `TextBox` in you user control code behind

```
public TextBox Name
{
    get { return txtName; }
    set { txtName = value; }
}
```

Now you can access your `TextBox` like this:

```
<uc1:UserDetails runat="server" ID="UserDetails1" />

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#<%= UserDetails1.Name.ClientID%>").val("set you text here");
            //or
            var name = $("#<%= UserDetails1.Name.ClientID %>").val();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using Jquery

```
$("[id$='txtName']").val();
$("[id$='txtAddress']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data keys inside your text boxes.

```
      --Start UserControl UserDetails--
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtName" data-key="name"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txtAddress" data-key="address"></asp:TextBox>
    --End UserControl UserDetails-

<uc1:UserDetails runat="server" ID="UserDetails1" data-usercontrol = "UserDetails1" />
```

in jquery,

```
$("[data-usercontrol='UserDetails1']").find("[data-key='name']").val();
$("[data-usercontrol='UserDetails1']").find("[data-key='address']").val();
```

You can use id selector. But since you have used asp.net, it might be rendered with different id in HTML.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the id of particular textbox from Developer Tools and then just use that id like below

**var textLength = $("#ContentBody_ucMFA1_txtACode").val().length;**

```js
 function Disable() {
            var textLength = $("#ContentBody_ucMFA1_txtACode").val().length;
            if (textLength > 0) {
                if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
                    document.getElementById("divButtons").style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting codes as images and post it as text instead. Because it will be hard to debug and cannot be copied to the code editor. And also put some details on how this address the OP's question.